# How do I filter the user who have logged in once in a view?

Tags: views, users

I need to create a view that shows the users who have logged in once to my site.
How can I implement this with Views?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [User Stats module](http://drupal.org/project/user_stats).  This will provide a count of how many times users log in and it integrates with [Views 2](http://drupal.org/project/views)